# No matching function for call to 'RCTAppSetupPrepareApp'

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode14

When running Archive in Xcode 14.2 of React Native code we run into this error in the AppDelegate file.

> No matching function for call to 'RCTAppSetupPrepareApp'

I am using React Native 0.71.7, react-native-cli: 2.0.1, and node 18.13.0

The code was supposed to be archived, but it isn't.

Answer (score 27):

I've fixed the issue with the following changes:

File: `AppDelegate.mm`

Before:

```
RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);
```

After:

```
RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application, true);
```

Before:

```
UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"Mobile", initProps);
```

After:

```
UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"Onboarding", initProps, true);
```

Thanks to `dimitardanailov` who answered in [here](https://codesti.com/issue/nrwl/nx/14399)

Comment: I have initProps not found

Comment: I used nil instead and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same error so I checked the actual version of react and previous I had when it worked last time. According to react-native upgrade helper, I see that this piece of code has changed and is no longer there. Check if this is not the case for you too.

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.6&to=0.71.2

Answer (score 2):

change **RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application)**;

TO

**RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application,true);**

And

**change UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"attendance", initProps)**

TO

****UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"attendance", initProps,true);****

And

**you might be need to clean the project after follow these steps**